# Windows 7 Batch if statement remove last slash

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, escaping, double-quotes

I'm trying to check a variable that contains a path to see if there is a trailing slash and if there is then remove it.  I have it working if the variable value is not surrounded by quotes but I also need to check for the trailing slash even if quotes exist.

The issue that I'm running into is trying to get an If statement to work to check for the double quote so I can basically check if it has a double quote and then check for the trailing slash.  The If statement fails with "( was unexpected at this time".  I'm sure it's an escaping issue but I've tried every way I can think of and haven't been able to get it to work.  I've been searching on the web for hours with no luck.

Here's what I have for it so far (I left out the code checking for it without the quotes, basically the same format).  Also, if there's a better way to achieve this I'm all ears.

```
set appRoot="C:\test\"

REM grab the last two characters
set lastChar=%appRoot:~-2%

if %lastChar% == \" (
    echo It works!
)
```

Comment: This *should* work, but for some reason I can't get this to run correctly. The syntax is right. My brain is melting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the line `if %lastChar% == \" (` is expanded (variables replaced with values), what you get is `if \" == \" (` which is not a valid condition, so the parenthesis is not expected.

With the value assigned to appRoot, your best option is directly check not the last but the previous character with

```
set "lastChar=%appRoot:~-2,1%"
if %lastChar% == \
```

Or, if you can change the value of appRoot

```
set "appRoot=C:\test\"

REM grab the last character
set lastChar=%appRoot:~-1%

if %lastChar% == \ (
    echo It works!
)
```

EDITED to adjust to comments

Since the OP don't have control on how the paths are asigned to the variables, the possible cases are: variables in the form `set var=`, `set var="path"`, `set var=path` or `set "var=path"` (we can assume the two last are equivalent if no special characters present). With or without trailing backslash. With or without spaces in path. And the need is to get a correct path (good looking, exists or not, this to be checked later), without trailing backslashes and (not in OP question, but should be) with or without quotes in a consistent manner.

So, here we go

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    set "appRoot=c:\some where\"
    call :cleanToFullPath appRoot 
    echo %appRoot%

    set "appRoot=c:\some where"
    call :cleanToFullPath appRoot
    echo %appRoot%

    set appRoot="c:\some where\"
    call :cleanToFullPath appRoot
    echo %appRoot%

    set appRoot="c:\some where\a\"
    call :cleanToFullPath appRoot
    echo %appRoot%

    set appRoot=c:\some where\in a rare place
    call :cleanToFullPath appRoot
    echo %appRoot%

    set appRoot=""
    call :cleanToFullPath appRoot
    echo %appRoot%

    goto :EOF

:cleanToFullPath variableName
    rem Prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem get variable name
    set "_varName=%~1"

    rem get value of variable
    set "_tmp=!%~1!"

    rem remove quotes from variable value
    set "_tmp=%_tmp:"=%" 

    rem handle empty variables. Default current folder
    if not defined _tmp set "_tmp=."

    rem prepare to process trailing bar if any
    if "%_tmp:~-1%"=="\" set "_tmp=%_tmp%."

    rem resolve to full path
    for %%# in ("%_tmp%") do set "_tmp=%%~f#"

    rem cleanup and update variable
    endlocal & set "%~1=%_tmp%"
    goto :eof
```

Comment: The value of appRoot is set by someone else (and there will be dozens of values) so that's the reason I would like to be able to check for both conditions: with or without the quotes.  The first option would not work correctly if there would be a one letter folder in the path.  i.e. C:\test\a.  I am using the value as a base path and appending a file name to it and the file should exist so I think the best route from here is to just check for the existence of the file.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it was going to be this complicated to do something that seems so trivial.  This works like a charm and great comments.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a robust method

```
@echo off
set appRoot="C:\test\"
for %%a in (%approot%) do for %%b in ("%%~a\.") do echo "%%~fb"
pause
```

If you can change the layout of quotes in the set statement then this is simpler:

```
@echo off
set "appRoot=C:\test\"
for %%a in ("%approot%\.") do echo "%%~fa"
pause
```

Comment: This works!  Can you explain the syntax?  I don't understand the "%%~a\." and "%%~fb".  
I can use this as `for %%a in (%approot%) do for %%b in ("%%~a\.") do set appRoot="%%~fb")`

Comment: @foxidrive: first approach have problems with variables defined without quotes but with spaces in path

Comment: @MCND:  You're right, I missed that.  This won't work for me then since I know we are using paths in "Program Files".

Comment: @MCND The variable is quoted in the same manner as the question in the first approach and spaces will not be a problem.  Note that the two approaches use different methods of quoting the variable.

Comment: @foxidrive, in the question, OP says he has to check for presence of quotes. And yes, the two approaches uses diferent methods. My comment was about the first one, in the case of no quotes and spaces in path. Second case assumes that the quoting method can be changed. If it is possible, that method has no problems. My original answer had the same error, assuming quotes should be present, and had to change when i realized i was wrong.

Comment: @mcnd I appreciate you're suggesting a fix, but it works fine with spaces in the path.  Try it with this: `set appRoot="C:\te st\abc & def\"` It is unreasonable not to quote a path that contains spaces and `&` for example and the OP's code is destined to fail at some point in the future if it is not quoted.  Maybe he is unaware of the `%%~a` term in a for loop.

Comment: @foxidrive, yes, with quotes it work, but OP doesn't know if variable will have quotes or not, spaces or not. Sure, it is unreasonable, but seems it can be the case.